# How to automatically update an object based on Account Type?

Tags: trigger

I want to automatically update a custom object: `Enquery__c` when ever I create an account which it's Type_c is `Prospect`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: What do you want to update in the "Enquery__c" object? Do you want to create a record or just update a field?

Comment: Are there any relationships between Enquery__c and Account? That could limit or open up possibilities.

Comment: Enquery is separate object there is no like between account and enquery. The field Type__c is picklist value you enter the picklist value is prospect in account object and automatically update  enquery__c object .

Comment: Just update Enquery object fields.

Comment: Can you explain about the relationship between Account and Enquery__c?

Comment: It sounds as though you're tring to ask how to ensure on a NEW Account or Insert Operation, `IF(Type__c = 'Prospect') enquery__c = 'Picklist Value A'`? If that's the case, you can add a workflow rule that will do that for you. You don't need a trigger when workflow a rule is much easier to implement. Another alternative would be to make Enquery__c a dependent picklist of Type__c, assuming they're both on the same object. Then `set the default value of Enquery__c when Type__c = 'Prospect'`. Otherwise, you need a validation rule that Enquery__c has an acceptable value when Type__c = Prospect.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is over three years old and you have yet to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3):

First you can write a trigger on Account for on Insert event and check the Account.Type__c == 'Prospect'.

If any record that matches the criteria, then which ever Enquery__c record is associated with that account just write a code for updating it.

Thanks

Comment: `Account.Type__c == 'Prospect'` would be evaluated as a declarative statement preventing it from being compiled. Type__c is a picklist, not a boolean.